# DynamoDB read spikes using scan

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a small job that runs every minute and perform a scan in a table that has near 3000 rows:

```
async execute (dialStatus) {
  if (!process.env.DIAL_TABLE) {
    throw new Error('Dial table not found')
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DIAL_TABLE,
    FilterExpression: '#name = :name AND #dial_status = :dial_status AND #expires_on > :expires_on',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#name': 'name',
      '#dial_status': 'dial_status',
      '#expires_on': 'expires_on'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':name': { 'S': this.name },
      ':dial_status': { 'S': dialStatus ? dialStatus : 'received' },
      ':expires_on': { 'N': Math.floor(moment().valueOf() / 1000).toString() }
    }
  }

  console.log('params', params)

  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB()
  const data = await dynamodb.scan(params).promise()
  return this._buildObject(data)
}
```

I'm facing a problem about read units and timeouts on dynamodb. Right now, I'm using 50 read units and it's getting expensive if compared to a RDS.

The attributes names used on scan function are not my primary key: `name` is a secondary index and `dial_status` is a normal attribute on my json but every row has this attribute.

This job run every minute for a list of parameters (i.e: if i have 10 parameters, I'll perform this `scan` 10 times in a minute).

My table has the following schema:

- phone (PK Hash)
- configuration: JSON in String format;
- dial_status String;
- expires_on: TTL number;
- name: String
- origin: String;

The job should get all items based on name and dial_status and the number of items is restricted to 15 elements each execution (each minute). For each element, it should be enqueued on SQS to be processed.

I really need to decrease those read units but I'm not sure on how optimize this function. I've read about reduce the page size or avoid scan. What's are my alternatives to avoid `scan` if I don't have primary key and I want to return a group of rows?

Any idea on how to fix this code to be called like 10-15 times every minute?

Comment: You should tell us more about your table schema and what this job does.

Comment: Check edit, please @MatthewPope

Comment: How are you processing things? Do you want each item processed exactly once, whenever it’s updated, daily, or something else?

Comment: Exactly one. When the item is processed, it should update column `dial_status`. Items are processed by another function and should update dynamodb when it's done. If possible, I could retrieve item, delete and send to sqs.

Comment: If you need exactly-once processing, then you should use DynamoDB Streams. Any sort of query or table scan will not scale well, as you have correctly identified. Check out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/

Comment: Not sure if Streams are a good option in my scenario. Each item represents a customer and I should make a phone call based on number of operators available. If the call fail, I should try again (this control is on SQS consumer). I don't want to work like a messaging service (stream) because I would like to reach my storage and say "hey storage, I need 13 items with name BANG right now". Is possible to perform queries on Dynamo Stream instead to have a consumer plugged on it?

Comment: I mean that I want to fetch data when It's necessary and not like an automatic delivery from stream.

Comment: You can’t query a stream in that way, but it sounds like streams are still the right solution for you. I’ll write up an answer explaining how.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a GSI (Global Secondary Index) with keys:

- HASH: `name_dialStatus`
- RANGE: `expiresOn`

As you've already guessed, the hash key has as value the concatenation of the two independent fields `name` and `dialStatus`.

Now you may use a query on this GSI, which is much more efficient since it doesn't scan all the table, but explores only the items you are interested in:

```
async execute(dialStatus) {
  if (!process.env.DIAL_TABLE) {
    throw new Error('Dial table not found')
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DIAL_TABLE,
    IndexName: 'MY_GSI_NAME',
    // replace `FilterExpression`
    // always test the partition key for equality!
    KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND #sk > :skLow', 
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#pk': 'name_dialStatus', // partition key name
      '#sk': 'expires_on' // sorting key name
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':pk': { 'S': `${this.name}:${dialStatus || 'received'}` },
      ':skLow': { 'N': Math.floor(moment().valueOf() / 1000).toString() }
    }
  }

  console.log('params', params)

  // Using AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() there is no need to specify the type of fields. This is a friendly advice :)
  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  // `scan` becomes `query` !!!
  const data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
  return this._buildObject(data);
}
```

Comment: Is safe to use `Limit`? Or `Limit` works like in a scan? It will get a number of items based on Limit and then apply my Expressions?

Comment: I do not consider `Limit` to be safe. When you start the scan you will visit a lot of items until you get the number of items specified by `Limit`. Thus you'll finish faster (then a full scan), but you'll still be late (it only depends on your **luck** and hash algorithms. mostly on your luck. do you fill lucky? :) ).  The query only visits the items you care about, no noise and no luck needed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to design dynamodb table based on access patterns to query it easily with keys(primarykey/sortkey) and to avoid expensive scan operations.

1. Revisit your table schema if it is not too late.
2. If it is already late then either create GSI with "name" as PrimaryKey and "expires_on" as SortKey with Projected attributes e.g. "dialStatus" so that you can query only required data to lower ready capacity.
3. If you still do not want to go with option 1 and option2 Scan operation with RateLimiter and pass only 25% of read capacity so that you can avoid spike.